# Preventing Shopify Dawn Theme from Automatically Choosing Product Variant

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid

The Shopify Dawn Theme automatically selects the first variant on a product page, which means the product variant photo shows up on page load instead of the featured product image. For example, if I'm selling a tennis shoe, and I offer the shoe in green, blue, and red, the product page will automatically select the green option on page load, and show the corresponding green shoe picture.

I want to prevent Shopify from automatically selecting the product variant. I've searched forum after forum, and have not found a solution that actually works. Any ideas?

I've tried editing the product-media-gallery.liquid file to force the main featured image to show up instead of the variant image. This doesn't effectively solve the problem, though, because the variant is still selected, and I do want the corresponding image to show up for each variant. I have not found a way to simply prevent the variant from being automatically selected.

Comment: I think you need to produce the working URL for this issue.